# How to use nextDouble after nextLine inside a while loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, printwriter

I am trying to read a file and write content from that file into a few different text files, but I can't get the program to write anything because I believe that I need to insert a nextLine() in here somewhere but I do not know where. I am new to this website and also new to java. Please help.

```
    while (readFile.hasNext())
    {

        m = readFile.nextLine();
        p = readFile.nextLine();
        double cos = readFile.nextDouble();
        double bof = readFile.nextDouble();

        profit = bof - cos;

        if (profit >= bb)
        {
            bold.println(m + "  " + p + "  " + formatter.format(profit));
        }
        else if (profit >= ss && profit <= bb)
        {
            solid.println(m + "  " + p + "  " + formatter.format(profit));
        }
        else if (profit >= eS && profit <= ss)
        {
            odd.println(m + "  " + p + "  " + formatter.format(profit));
        }
        else
        {
            flo.println(m + "  " + p + "  " + formatter.format(profit));
        }
    }
```

Comment: If nothing is being printed (ie there is no error, it just runs and does nothing), then either your readFile is empty or your `bold`/`solid`/`odd`/`flo` `.println` methods do not work.

Comment: I made sure my readFile isn't empty and I know my methods work because I removed m and p and the program ran perfectly when their were only doubles involved.

Comment: Wait, does the program actually terminate, or is it waiting for input? Try putting a `println` statement after the end of the `while` to see whether the program reaches it.

Comment: There is no input. I'm using File to read a text document and split the info from the text document amongst 4 other text documents. And I do have a println after the while to verify if the info was moved.

Comment: What does System.out.println(readFile.useDelimiter("\u0000").next("[^\u0000]*")); display? What is printed if you simplify out your methods and simply feed each variable directly into System.out?

Comment: It says Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor<Scanner.java:864>
at java.util.Scanner.next<Scanner.java:1485>
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble<Scanner.java:2413>

Comment: That code just prints the entire file (usually); put it outside the while. What about printing the values of your variables?

Answer (score 1):

You should consume the end of line after reading the doubles:

```
    m = readFile.nextLine();
    p = readFile.nextLine();
    double cos = readFile.nextDouble();
    double bof = readFile.nextDouble();
    readFile.nextLine();
```

Comment: That's what I thought also, but when I do that it shows errors in the console saying no line found.